# making two input forms in a webpage (Django)

Tags: python, html, django, forms, input

I made two input forms(① and ②) in a webpage, but both did not work properly.

in ① format,{{form_1.as_p}} is working well, but <input type="text“ name="user_input_income"...> isn't working

in ② format, <input type="text" name="user_input_withdrawal"..> is not working.

Actually, what I want to form is ② format. How can I change the code for ② format ?

The problem is explained in more detail as the following image.

please help and thank you for your help in advance.

[image]

<views.py>

```
def input(request):
    items_income= Memo_income.objects.all()
    items_withdrawal = Memo_withdrawal.objects.all()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        if 'user_input_withdrawal' in request.POST:
            form = InputForm2(request.POST, prefix='user_input_withdrawal')
            if form.is_valid():
            # Get the ID from the form data
                item_id = request.POST.get('id')
            # Fetch the item by ID
                item = get_object_or_404(Memo_withdrawal,id=item_id)
            # Update the item with the new data from the form
                item.user_input_withdrawal = form.cleaned_data['user_input_withdrawal']
            # Update other fields as needed
                item.save()
                return redirect('input')  # Redirect to the table display page after updating
        
        elif 'user_input_income' in request.POST:
            form = InputForm1(request.POST, prefix='user_input_income')
            if form.is_valid():
                item_id = request.POST.get('id')
                item = get_object_or_404(Memo_income,id=item_id)
                item.user_input_income = form.cleaned_data['user_input_income']
                item.save()
                return redirect('input')
    else: #the logic for handling Http GET request
        form1=InputForm1(prefix='user_input_income')
        form2 = InputForm2(prefix='user_input_withdrawal')

    return render(request, 'report/input.html', {'items_income':items_income, 'items_withdrawal': items_withdrawal,'form1':form1,'form2':form2})
```

<input.html>

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>적요(저장내역)</th>
            <th>입금 종류(저장내역)</th>
            <th>변경사항 입력</th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in items_income %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.memo_income }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.user_input_income }}</td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form1.as_p}}
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ item.id }}">
                    <input type="text" name="user_input_income" value="{{ item.user_input_income }}">
                    <!-- Add other fields as needed -->
                    <input type="submit" value="Update">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

<table>
        <tr>
            <th>적요(저장내역)</th>
            <th>지출 종류(저장내역)</th>
            <th>변경사항 입력</th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in items_withdrawal %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.memo_withdrawal }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.user_input_withdrawal }}</td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ item.id }}">
                    <input type="text" name="user_input_withdrawal" value="{{ item.user_input_withdrawal }}">
                    <!-- Add other fields as needed -->
                    <input type="submit" value="Update">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

<forms.py>

```
class InputForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Memo_income
        fields=['user_input_income']

class InputForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Memo_withdrawal
        fields=['user_input_withdrawal']
```

Comment: Your forms are the same, also both of them don't have action url. It would be much easier for you if you split your function into to different urls with two different function

Comment: I tried to find the way for some days, but i did not find the solution. As your adive, I made two url and different funtions, which worked very well. thank you for your advice.